# Auction Makrets and delearship markets

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

The largest difference is that the NYSE is an auction market and the Nasdaq is a dealer market. In the former, the highest bid for a stock is matched with the lowest asking price. In the latter, buying and selling happens in split seconds electronically through dealers. Could someone be more illustrative about the prhase ``the highest bid for a stock is matched with the lowest asking price" with some paradigm?

Comment: Unfortunately the sentence "*the highest bid for a stock is matched with the lowest asking price*" is in plain English, so it is not clear what intuition you are asking for.

Comment: Besides the opening and closing auctions, trading/price discovery on NYSE occurs via limit order book, just like Nasdaq (and most other major exchanges around the workd).

Comment: What i understant in plain English is the following. Suppose that 50 traders make a bid for the stock and 200 made want to sell it. So the trader who made the highest bid (from the 50 traders) matches with one of the 200 traders, the one who is willing to sell at the lowset price. Then the second trader (of the 50) with the second highest bid matches with the second one of the 200 who has the second lowest asking price...Am I right?

Comment: You want to look up limit order book/limit order/market order/best bid and ask, as well as opening and closing auctions.

Comment: Ok I will do so, do you have any textbook to suggest? Also, my thoughts above are not so close to the answer...Am I totally wrong?